# How to store windows system path in JMeter JSR223 sampler using groovy strings?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am building a config in Jmeter where I specializing a system windows path to load CSV and write into CSV files. The path contains "" symbol.
There are some samplers with JSR223 PreProcessors and JSR223 Samplers. Language used is Groovy.
I know that I should screen symbols such this, but I am a bit lost at the moment because I do not understand why different options work sometimes and do not other times.
Initial path is "C:\user\jmeter\csv"
How I define this in jMeter JSR223:

```
def systemPath = "C:\\user\\jmeter\\csv\\"
```

Sometimes it works, but after I've changed some lines of code it won't!
Next time I've tried:

```
def systemPath = "C:\\\user\\\jmeter\\\csv\\\"
```

It worked for me for a while but after some code alterations after this line it won't work again.
I also 've read an article https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-strings and tried everything, but still I get this error every time:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script343.groovy: 2: Unexpected input: '"' @ line 2, column 16.
   def systemPath = "C:\user\jmeter\csv\";
```

I want to store this system path reliably without errors and understand why I get this error.

Comment: I've tried path like
def systemPath = "C:/user/jmeter/csv/"
and it worked for me in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with this line:

```
def systemPath = "C:\\user\\jmeter\\csv\\"
```

[image]

this one is not good:

```
def systemPath = "C:\\\user\\\jmeter\\\csv\\\"
```

[image]

Your "work sometimes and do not other times" statement doesn't add any value unless you show [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug level of verbosity](http://work%20sometimes%20and%20do%20not%20other%20times) for "working" and "not working" cases.

---

For the time being consider the following hints:

- You can use forward slashes instead of escaping, i.e.

  ```
   def systemPath = "C:/user/jmeter/csv/"
  ```
- Or you can use [File.separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) property to get OS-specific "slash" value like:

  ```
   def systemPath = "C:" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator + "jmeter" + File.separator + "csv" + File.separator
  ```

  [image]
- If you think that `"` character is a problem (it needs to be escaped as well by the way) you can declare Groovy strings using `'` characters like:

  ```
   def systemPath = 'C:\\user\\jmeter\\csv\\'
  ```